# Использование DLL в Node.js

Tags: node.js, dll

Как в проекте Node.js подключить библиотеку DLL и использовать функции из этой библиотеки?

Comment: https://medium.com/doctolib/calling-into-thread-unsafe-dlls-with-node-ffi-1ef83806a50c

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать используя [winax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winax):

```
const winax = require('winax');
const sbrf = new winax.Object('SBRFSRV.Server');

const opPinpadCheckResultCode = sbrf.NFun(7003);
console.log(opPinpadCheckResultCode, opPinpadCheckResultCode === 0 ? 'пинпад есть' : 'пинпада нет');
sbrf.clear();
```